# Is a clone statement ever optimised out?

Tags: memory, rust, clone

I have code similar to the following

```
let x = Arc::new(Mutex::new(Thing::new()));

work_on_data(x.clone());
do_more_work_on_data(x.clone());
```

`x` isn't used after the second function and therefore the second clone is not required. Should I remove the `clone()` manually, or is it optimised out?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Why not?**

The over-arching principle of an optimizing compiler is the *as-if rule*, which specifies that anything can be optimized as long as the compiler can prove that the optimization is not observable.

*Note: this comes on top of some languages allowing specific optimizations.*

So for example:

```
#[derive(Clone, Debug)]
struct MyDummyType(u64);

extern {
    fn print_c(_: *const ());
}

#[inline(never)]
fn print(dummy: MyDummyType) {
    unsafe { print_c(&dummy as *const _ as *const _) }
}

fn main() {
    let x = MyDummyType(42);
    print(x.clone());
    print(x.clone());
}
```

Yields the following `main`:

```
; Function Attrs: nounwind uwtable
define internal void @_ZN8rust_out4main17h0c6f2596c7f28a79E() unnamed_addr #1 {
entry-block:
  tail call fastcc void @_ZN8rust_out5print17h1f2d1a86beea10d7E(i64 42)
  tail call fastcc void @_ZN8rust_out5print17h1f2d1a86beea10d7E(i64 42)
  ret void
}
```

The compiler completely saw through our code (and I actually had to use an extern function to force it to emit *some* code in `main`).

---

So, what about your case?

It's quite more difficult, to be honest.

Specifically, there's a potential change of semantics due to `Drop`:

- with `do_more_work_on_data(x.clone())`, `x` is guaranteed to be dropped *after* the execution ends, and therefore any side-effect of `Drop` to be executed *at the end of the current function*,
- with `do_more_work_on_data(x)`, `x` *may* be dropped at the end of `do_more_work_on_data` OR it may be dropped earlier somewhere within.

So in order to prove that the optimization *is not observable*, the compiler has to prove:

- either that `Drop` has no effect,
- or that `Drop` will be executed at the very end of `do_more_work_on_data`, which is the same as right after it,
- or ...?

How likely is this?

The `Drop` implementation of `Mutex` requires invoking FFI, so from the optimizer point of view it *has* observable effects.

So it all hinges on whether `do_more_work_on_data` gets inlined. If it does, yes indeed the extra `clone` could well be optimized out. If it does not, I would not hold my breath.

Answer (score 4):

Clone might print something out or write to a file. Optimizing the clone out changes behaviour and therefore cannot be done.

Of course, if the compiler has full knowledge of what clone is doing and can work out that it can never have side-effects, it may well optimize it out but don't hold your breath.

As a general rule, if you know a function will always return the same value, cache the value in a variable rather than calling a function a number of times.

Comment: acutally he could remove the last clone right? `do_more_work...` will just take posession of x then, since `x` is not used anymore it makes sense. Or im i wrong?

Comment: That's awfully pessimistic.

Comment: *(To clarify my comment)* You are assuming that the `clone` implementation is opaque, however it's not (necessarily) the case, and whenever it's transparent to the optimizer, then the optimizer can have the guarantee that `clone` has no observable side-effects. I am much more concerned about `Drop`, for this particular case, but the general answer is clearly **Yes, of course sometimes it gets optimized out**.

Comment: I assumed from the question that the OP was familiar with the as-if rule which applies everywhere and not specifically to clone but thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: @MatthieuM. I have now added this point in. Please feel free to modify my answer if you can express it better.